# how to create a report based on date subscription to a group?

Tags: civireport

I need to have a report that shows members according to their date of being part of a chosen group. I can select by group but not by date of being in this group.

Is this possible?

(I have a special process for membership that includes a control step to fully validate the membership. We have to check some documents so there can be a delay between "civicrm membership" and our membership.)

thanks for your ideas

G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under custom searches there is a search you can use for date range of subscription to a group. You could then create a smart group from the results if needed. Its called "Search Group Subscription by Date Range"

Comment: I don't think this is a custom report in the standard distribution. I can't see it.

Comment: Thanks Parvez, this was exactly was I was looking for.

Comment: Further to my earlier comment, you need to have the GDPR extension installed to get this option, which is why I couldn't find it. But it looks better than my suggestion below as it shows all the history not just the latest value.

Comment: Thanks Mick, we install it as part of our deployments, thats why I missed that its a _custom_ custom search

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension that provides a report to do this https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory that does this.

Comment: also good. thanks!

Comment: But the other option is better as it displays the whole history, not just one value. And I've just found that when I add/remove/add/remove, that it doesn't show the latest status (added) if you don't filter status but does show removed if you filter by that status. So I have voted for the other option!